# Table construction: Very Simple Beginner's Question

Tags: html, height, cell

I have just begun learning elementary 'coding' (HTML) and I'm stuck on a table my teacher presented us for the long weekend (note that I'm on vacation so this is not counting towards any degree and I'm not seeing him until Tuesday). I gather that it's probably a very straightforward solution but I've been wrestling with it since the afternoon.

The linked-to image file shows the table he wants us to construct using nothing but HTML (no CSS). I'm supposed that there are those who'll descry this as not being modern technique but I imagine it wouldn't be bad to know how to at least achieve this using straight-up HTML.

The top row is one long box (say it has one unit of height), the second row from the top comprises two boxes of three units in height, the third from the top row is another long, one-unit high box on top of the bottom-most, one-unit-high five boxes, each of equal size.

The boxes are all empty of data though he drew two large X's in the large boxes][1] to show that THOSE cells would have 'X' placeholders and not be blank. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK7oJ.png

The fledgling HTML code I've managed to come up with is this:

```html
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Under the Table</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <center> <h2>Table Example</h1></center>
     <center>
      <table border="3">
        <tr>   
         <th colspan="5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td colspan="2.50" height="100"; width="100"><center>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</center></td>
         <td colspan="2.50" height="100"; width="100"><center>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</center></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td colspan="5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
         
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
         <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
         <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
         <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
         <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
         
        </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Run the code and you'll see that while everything seems fine the second row with the triple-height boxes are compressed, leaving a large space in the right-hand part of the row. Just run the code and you'll see my issue.

Okay, so to summarize and state it explicitly: I am unable to create a table with eight empty boxes and two large (triple-height) boxes with a single character within them using nothing but HTML (I probably couldn't manage by any other means either but still). Any advice based both on the desired output (picture) and my last failed attempt (whose two large boxes in the second row are too small horizontally and leave an empty non-cell space)?

NB: I'm on vacation and this is not a degree course. Because I'm on additional holiday for a long weekend I was hoping for some input from people who know about markup language (and programming in general). Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

So the colspan argument does not accept a decimal. What you can do in this case is to simple multiply your columns by 2 so you get 10 for the first and third row which means the second row would be 2 instead of 2.50. You'll however probably not achieve a very good end result with that either since your 4:th will only be 50% (10% * 5) in the code you have.

I really don't want to give you all the anwers here if this is for school but you can play around with it if you want to see what happens.

Comment: I think your solutions is pragmatic and good. Although it might be very interesting to see at least hits to "all the answers" ;-)